# TikZ: path-style syntax upside-down tree for adpositional grammars

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics

I would like to reproduce in TikZ the following adpositional path-like adpositional tree, that I am able to draw in full only by hand. See here:

[image: path-like adtree of 'the girl for wh-om the man bought the book']

**First MWE**: my minimal working example (MWE) using `tikz-dependency` succeed only to produce the text, not the paths, as arrows always points at cells. This is perfectly fine for dependency trees and that package is great for this purpose, but I need something different here.

Any alternative idea is welcome, not necessarily with this package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}

\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1em]
the \& girl \& for \& wh- \& om \& the \& man \& bought \& the \& book\\
A \& O \& U \& U \& O \& A \& O \& I \& A \& O\\
\end{deptext}
\end{dependency}

\end{document}
```

[image: my MWE output here]

I do not know how to draw such paths with `tex-dependency`, only arrows that points to words.

**Second MWE** I tried to use `forest` then, but I am not able to produce a satisfying result. Here the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\bracketset{action character=@}
\newcount\xcount
\def\x#1{@@\advance\xcount1
\edef\xtemp{[$\noexpand\times_{\the\xcount}$[#1]]}%
\expandafter\bracketResume\xtemp
}
\begin{forest}
phantom,
delay={where level=1{content={\strut #1}}{}}
@+
[
\x{the [A[.]] }
\x{girl [O[.]] }
\x{for [U[.]] }
\x{wh- [U[.]] }
\x{om [O[.]] }
\x{the  [A[.]] }
\x{man [O[.]] }
\x{bought [I[.]] }
\x{the [A[.]] }
\x{book [O[.]]}]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This is the output of the second MWE:

[image]

I think paths should be identified with three parameters:

1. starting point -- e.g. start the path below 'girl' and 'O';
2. depth -- e.g. go 6 in the path below 'girl' and 'O';
3. arrow direction; this can be:

   - none, e.g. the path below 'girl' and 'O';
   - right, e.g. go 1 right in the path below the 'the' on the left of 'girl';
   - left, e.g. go 4 left in the path below 'bought' and 'I';

If arrow direction is left or right, next to the arrow head there should be an extra parameter for the final grammar character of the path such as in the figure, which probably would be something like `\overleftarrow{O}` for the path starting under 'girl' and 'O' and `\overrightarrow{A}` for the path starting under 'bought' and 'I';

The last features are the "bridges" (I do not have a better name) on depth 1 (right-side bridge) and 4 (left-side bridge) for the path starting under the 'wh' and 'U'.

Any suggestion on any TikZ-based package is more than welcome.

Comment: I noticed that you must have posted while I was writing the comment.  I will delete the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly not yet a full answer, just to tell you that I do not agree with your scepticism on the package. IMHO this is a package with an extremely well-written manual, and here is why I believe you can achieve what you want with it. The key ingredient of this answer is a macro

```
\Connect{<start>}{<end>}{<level>}{<label>}
```

where `start`, `end` *and* `level` are all integers. Its use is illustrated by the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} % not used ... YET
\newcounter{depaths}
\newcommand{\Connect}[5][]{
\stepcounter{depaths}
\draw[name path=dep connect \thedepaths](\wordref{2}{#2}) -- ++ (0,-#4) coordinate (aux-\thedepaths-1)  -| 
(\wordref{2}{#3}) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux-\thedepaths-2);
\draw[-latex,shorten >=1pt] (aux-\thedepaths-1) -- (aux-\thedepaths-2);
\ifnum#3>#2
\node[anchor=south east] at (aux-\thedepaths-2) {#5};
\else
\node[anchor=south west] at (aux-\thedepaths-2) {#5};
\fi
\foreach \X in {1,...,#4}
{\fill (\wordref{2}{#2}) ++ (0,-\X) circle(1.5pt); 
\fill (\wordref{2}{#3}) ++ (0,-\X) circle(1.5pt);}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\DeltaX}{abs(#3-#2)}
\ifnum\DeltaX>1
\foreach \X in {#2,...,#3}
\fill (\wordref{2}{\X}) ++ (0,-#4) circle(1.5pt);
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1em]
the \& girl \& for \& wh- \& om \& the \& man \& bought \& the \& book\\
A \& O \& U \& U \& O \& A \& O \& I \& A \& O\\
\end{deptext}
\Connect{1}{2}{1}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\Connect{4}{2}{6}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\Connect{4}{3}{1}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\end{dependency}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: This is an *experimental* version that draws arcs over intersections. As you can see, there are quite a number of `\typeout`s and this is by far not perfect, but perhaps a start. To be more precise, the arcs won't be drawn whenever one of the following criteria is met:

1. The first path starts where the second path starts or ends.
2. The first path ends where the second path starts or ends.
3. The paths have the same level (=3rd parameter of the macro `\Connect{4}{3}{1}`).

It is easy to see that if any of those criteria are met, there is a great chance that there shouldn't be an arc, but the following two paths won't have an arc either:

```
******************
 |   | |
 *---*-*
     | |
     *-*
```

It is possible, though cumbersome, to close this loophole also. Depending on whether this will *really* also get used somewhere, I may pick up enough motivation to do that and also to make the macros more Ti*k*Zy, i.e. work with pgfkeys.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} 
\newcounter{depaths}
\newif\ifIntersect
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture={%
\xdef\LstPaths{}% may be unnecessary
\setcounter{depaths}{0}}}}
\newcommand{\Connect}[5][]{
\stepcounter{depaths}%\typeout{new\space path\space\thedepaths}
\draw[name path=dep connect \thedepaths-tmp](\wordref{2}{#2}) -- ++ (0,-#4) coordinate (aux-\thedepaths-1)  -| 
(\wordref{2}{#3}) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux-\thedepaths-2);
\draw[-latex,shorten >=1pt] (aux-\thedepaths-1) -- (aux-\thedepaths-2);
\ifnum#3>#2
  \node[anchor=south east] at (aux-\thedepaths-2) {#5};
\else
  \node[anchor=south west] at (aux-\thedepaths-2) {#5};
\fi
\foreach \X in {1,...,#4}
{\fill (\wordref{2}{#2}) ++ (0,-\X) circle(1.5pt); 
\fill (\wordref{2}{#3}) ++ (0,-\X) circle(1.5pt);}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\DeltaX}{abs(#3-#2)}
\ifnum\DeltaX>1
\foreach \X in {#2,...,#3}
\fill (\wordref{2}{\X}) ++ (0,-#4) circle(1.5pt);
\fi
\ifnum\thedepaths>1  
  \foreach \Y [count=\X] in \LstPaths
  {\Intersectfalse
  %\typeout{checking\space intersection\space with\space path\space \X}
  \path[name intersections={of=dep connect \thedepaths-tmp and dep
  connect \X-tmp,total=\t}] \pgfextra{%\typeout{\t:\Y}
  \ifnum\t>0
  \global\Intersecttrue
  %\typeout{paths\space\X\space and\space\thedepaths \space\space have\space common\space points}
  \fi};  
  \foreach \V [count=\W] in \Y
  {\ifcase\W % no 0
  \or % 1 boring
  \or % 2
   \ifnum\V=#2
    %\typeout{case2-2}
    \global\Intersectfalse
   \fi
   \ifnum\V=#3
    %\typeout{case2-3}
    \global\Intersectfalse
   \fi
  \or
   \ifnum\V=#3
    %\typeout{case3-3}
    \global\Intersectfalse
   \fi
   \ifnum\V=#2
    %\typeout{case3-2}
    \global\Intersectfalse
   \fi
  \or
   \ifnum\V=#4
    %\typeout{case4}
    \global\Intersectfalse
   \fi
  \fi}  
  \ifIntersect
   \node[circle,fill=white,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt] (aux-int) at (intersection-1){};
   \draw (aux-int.south) -- (aux-int.north);
   \draw[white,double=black] (aux-int.west) to[out=60,in=120] (aux-int.east);
   %\typeout{real\space intersection\space of\space path\space \thedepaths\space with\space path\space \X}
  \fi
  }
\fi
\ifnum\thedepaths=1
  \xdef\LstPaths{{\thedepaths,#2,#3,#4}}
\else
  \xdef\LstPaths{\LstPaths,{\thedepaths,#2,#3,#4}}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1em]
the \& marmot \& for \& wh- \& om \& the \& duck \& bought \& the \& cake\\
A \& O \& U \& U \& O \& A \& O \& I \& A \& O\\
\end{deptext}
\Connect{1}{2}{1}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\Connect{4}{2}{6}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\Connect{3}{8}{4}{$\overleftarrow{3}$}
\Connect{5}{3}{1}{$\overleftarrow{O}$}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you were faster than my comment!

Comment: The result is already impressive. No, you are not missing anything! Intersections are the only things missing. I've seen an example here http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/line-junction.tex and I will try to understand how it works. Thank you a lot again!

Comment: +1 for the conditionals...

Comment: @JLeonV. Thanks! Actually this is a real mess since the paths technically intersect but are not considered intersecting as they "only" merge. I actually feel very bad, given that the starting point is a really nice package where everything is fully customizable in pgfkeys, and I add the code of a wood chopper (or wood chuck? ;-) ...

Comment: @marmot, yes but there are structures in your code that I did not know what could be done ... and well, it is useful to apply in other drawings, of course referring to this self-denying marmot...

Comment: @JLeonV. No, it's more the thing : "Oh, this can't be that complicated"... and 15 `\typeout`s later you realize "Well, it is complicated" and you write an answer, in which you declare the post to be experimental and forget about it. ;-) But yes, [others seem to agree with you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GHfo.png) ;-)